# Getting Xelement.elements() using a path

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have some xml like this.

```
 <Map>
  <Pr>
    <Dir .... >
    <Dir .... >
  </Pr>
 </Map>
```

I have the parent element to call .Elements on. I looked this up, but I cant figure out how to do get the element Pr directly

```
XElement element = (from item in parentElement.Elements("Map/Pr") select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Path I provided seems to be incorrect. Whats the right format? I tried "Map" + "Pr" or "//Map/Pr" etc.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`XElement.XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083(v=vs.90).ASPX) method if you wanna select an element using `XPath`, `Elements` method takes an element name not a `Path`.

```
XElement element = parentElement.XPathSelectElement("Map/Pr");
```

Or use `parentElement.Descendants("Pr")` if you want to get all `Pr` elements.

Comment: Could also use Elements("Map").Elements("Pr") if you don't want all descendants.

Comment: Took me a couple minutes to realize that this was an extension method and that I needed to import the XPath namespace with `using System.Xml.XPath;` in order to have access to `XPathSelectElement` on `XElement`. Perhaps obvious in retrospect, but maybe this helps someone else.